# Why Kdenlive in Ubuntu cannot access windows folder?

Tags: kdenlive

I found a strange thing. When I use KDENLIVE （20.04version) under UBUNTU 20.04, if I use the menu--project--add clip or folder, I cannot see the windows directory that I have alreday mounted. For example, I use this command:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda4 /home/sunjar/windows/d -o uid=1000,gid=1000
```

When I use the 'open' menu in other software such as libreoffice or audacity, I can see the directory contents which is /home/sunjar/windows/d, and I can read and write them normally, but only kdenlive does not work. Did I missed something? Or is this a bug?

Comment: How did you install kdenlive? Via PPA? AppImage? Other method?

Comment: @erjiang Hi, I installed kdenlive from Ubuntu software center. Just now I reinstalled kdenlive from APT method, the version became 19.12.3, but now it works, thank you!

Comment: That could explain it... I will write why in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Applications installed via Flatpak or Snap (which might be the case if installed from the software center) may be running in a sandbox for security reasons, which can limit what directories they can access. I have had issues with Gimp not able to access `/tmp` when installed from Snap, for example.

I prefer using the AppImage version of Kdenlive downloaded directly from their website which is more up-to-date than the version available in Ubuntu's APT repository. It does not run in a sandbox.